# FB.Login callback is not called on background-activation

Tags: android, facebook, authentication, unity-game-engine, onresume

I'm using Facebook Unity SDK 5.0.3-beta and Unity3d 4.3.4 in Android 4.2

I made "Facebook Login" button in unity app which calls FB.Login on click

and I want to disable the login button until FB.Login 'callback' function is called.

```
   function OnClickLogin()
   {
          DisableLoginButton();
          FB.Login("email", callback);
   }


   function callback(FBResult result)
   {
          if (result.Error != null) // FB-Login fail
              EnableLoginButton();
          else
              ....
   }
```

[Situation A]

while FB-login windows appears on screen, I press home key and

re-activate the my app from background state (by touching app icon in main screen)

FB-login windows disappears in this situation.

After that, the login button is disabled in my app. And 'callback' will never be called.

---

[Situation B]

while FB-login windows appears on screen, I press home key and

re-activate the app by selecting the my app in 'running-app list'

(press home key awhile, you can see 'running-app list')

FB-login windows appears on my app, and after FB-login, 'callback' is called properly.

Answer (score 0):

**On Android you should use the native Facebook SDK for Android.**

- This should eliminate the issues described in Situations A&B.
- It will also be necessary to make it through Facebook's Submission.

Here is a link to ->  [Facebook's Android SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android)